# Cannot run my template in .dbt extension in Oracle 12c DBCA

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

The following is my template file `testing.dbt`. I kept it under `C:\app\ORCLUSER\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\assistants\dbca\templates`. I'm trying to create it from Oracle 12c (Enterprise) DBCA. When I select create database and choose it. It says, the template file is in invalid template file and it is not in the expected mode. Please help me with this.

[This is my testing.dbt file](https://myte.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZwSiaZ8dIhVbnevAY6VFS5TirSXjKWs9pX)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing the same problem: the reason of the error "The template data is not in the expected format" may be different interpretation of negative values between the different versions of DBCA.

Deletion of the following tags with negative values in the Testing.dbt attached by OP does the trick:

```
initSize
blockSize
increment
incrementPercent
minExtendsSize
minExtends
maxExtends
maxSize
uniAllocSize
id
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some bugs related to it.

Possible workaround is to remove following template sections:

```
- <reuse>true</reuse>
- <Variables>

and ALL <incrementPercent> sections
```